# Conway's Game of Life in Powershell

Tags: beginner, powershell, game-of-life

I'm learning PowerShell for professional development, but decided to do a bit of a silly project to help learn scripting in more depth, and chose [Conway's Game of Life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life). This is the first PowerShell script I've written besides a small toy that I wrote for an Active Directory assignment previously.

An example start:

```powershell
PS C:\Users\user\PowershellScripts> . .\gol.ps1
PS C:\Users\user\PowershellScripts> Start-Main 15 15 0.3

--------------------------------------------------
  █ █ █ █ █       █ █ █ █     
█ █   █ █ █ █               █ 
              █         █ █   
  █         █ █
                  █ █
                    █ █ █   █ 
                      █   █ █ 
                        █ █ █
  █       █ █           █ █ █ 
    █     █               █ █ 
      █   █ █ █ █   █     █ █ 
        █ █   █ █     █       
      █ █     █     █ █ █   █ 
      █ █       █ █ █ █ █   █ 
      █ █                   █
```

Primarily, I'd like comments on anything stylistic or off that I'm doing so I don't develop bad habits.

Also, I'd like to know how I could make it perform better. Obviously I wasn't expecting speed here, but it's surprisingly slow. I was originally abusing range notation to make the looping a little nicer looking, and doing things like `$NNeighbors -in 2..3` to do range checks, but ended switching those over to more traditional `for` loops and comparison checks.

Also, I wanted to play around with defining constants using `New-Variable`, but it ended up being awkward. Whenever I reloaded the script, I'd get an error because a constant with the same name already existed. I ended up using a C-style `ifndef`-like check at the start, but this feels off.

There's no tag for it, but in case it matters, this was written with for Powershell 7.

```powershell
if ($null -eq $MOORE_NEIGHBORHOOD_DEPTH) {  # Since reloading script in a shell will cause errors otherwise
    Set-Variable -Name MOORE_NEIGHBORHOOD_DEPTH -Value 1 -Option Constant
    Set-Variable -Name ALIVE_CELL_REPR -Value "█" -Option Constant
    Set-Variable -Name DEAD_CELL_REPR -Value " " -Option Constant
}
    
# The state holds an array of cells to read from, and an array of cells to write to.
# Each cell array holds a boolean value indicating if it's alive or not.
function New-State {
    Param($Width, $Height)
    $Total = $Width * $Height
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        ReadCells = (,$false) * $Total;
        WriteCells = (,$false) * $Total;
        Width = $Width;
        Height = $Height;
    }
}

function New-RandomState {
    Param($Width, $Height, $AliveChance)
    $State = New-State $Width $Height
    for ($I = 0; $I -lt $State.ReadCells.Length; $I++) {
        if ((Get-Random -Minimum 0.0 -Maximum 1.0) -lt $AliveChance) {
            $State.ReadCells[$I] = $true
        }
    }
    
    $State
}

# Swaps the read and write cell arrays so the read array is written to, and the write array is read from. 
function Switch-Cells {
    Param($State)

    $Temp = $State.ReadCells
    $State.ReadCells = $State.WriteCells
    $State.WriteCells = $Temp
}

# A 1D-array is being used to emulate a 2D-array.
# This calculates the index into the array to simulate X,Y coordinate access.
function Get-Index {
    Param($State, $X, $Y)

    $State.Width * $Y + $X
}


function Confirm-Alive {
    Param($State, $X, $Y)

    $State.ReadCells[(Get-Index $State $X $Y)]
}

# Counts how many neighbors surrounding the given cell are alive.
# Depth is how many squares in each direction from the given cell to search (1 cooresponds to a Moore neighborhood)
function Find-NeighborCount {
    Param($State, $X, $Y, $Depth)
    $XMinBound = [math]::max(0, $X-$Depth)
    $XMaxBound = [math]::min($X+$Depth, $State.Width-1)
    $YMinBound = [math]::max(0, $Y-$Depth)
    $YMaxBound = [math]::min($Y+$Depth, $State.Height-1)

    $Count = 0
    for ($FY = $YMinBound; $FY -le $YMaxBound; $FY++) {
        for ($FX = $XMinBound; $FX -le $XMaxBound; $FX++) {
            if ((-not ($X -eq $FX -and $Y -eq $FY)) -and (Confirm-Alive $State $FX $FY)) {
                $Count++
            }
        }
    }

    $Count
}

# Updates the given cell according to how many of its neighbors are found to be alive.
function Update-Cell {
    Param($State, $X, $Y)
    $CurrentlyAlive = Confirm-Alive $State $X $Y
    $NNeighbors = Find-NeighborCount $State $X $Y $MOORE_NEIGHBORHOOD_DEPTH
    $NewState = $CurrentlyAlive -and (2 -le $NNeighbors -and $NNeighbors -le 3) -or
                  ((-not $CurrentlyAlive) -and $NNeighbors -eq 3)
    $State.WriteCells[(Get-Index $State $X $Y)] = $NewState
}

function Update-Cells {
    Param($State)
    for ($Y = 0; $Y -lt $State.Height; $Y++) {
        for ($X = 0; $X -lt $State.Width; $X++) {
            Update-Cell $State $X $Y
        }
    }
}

# Writes the state of the read cells to the screen.
function Show-State {
    Param($State)
    Write-Host ("-" * 50)
    for ($Y = 0; $Y -lt $State.Height; $Y++) {
        for ($X = 0; $X -lt $State.Width; $X++) {
            Write-Host "$($State.ReadCells[(Get-Index $State $X $Y)] ? $ALIVE_CELL_REPR : $DEAD_CELL_REPR) " -NoNewline
        }
        Write-Host ""
    }
}

function Write-DebugGlider {
    Param($State)
    function cell {
        Param($X, $Y)
        $State.WriteCells[(Get-Index $State $X $Y)] = $true
    }
    cell 1 0
    cell 2 1
    cell 0 2
    cell 1 2
    cell 2 2
}

function Start-Main {
    Param($Width, $Height, $AlivePercChance)
    $State = New-RandomState $Width $Height $AlivePercChance

    for ($N = 0; $N -lt 100; $N++) {
        Update-Cells $State
        Switch-Cells $State
        Show-State $State
        #Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 250
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a fun project.
Here are a few things I noticed:

1. `$AlivePercChance` implies that it's a percentage (30%) rather than a fraction (0.3). You might consider renaming it to `$AliveChance`
2. Why did you flatten the 2D array to 1D? It adds substantial overhead (2 extra function calls * $Width * $Height per screen write, way more for checking neighbors) and reduces readability compared to `$State.ReadCells[$x,$y]`.
3. The program works in Powershell 5 except for the ternary operator on line 102, which you can change to:
   `Write-Host "$(If($State.ReadCells[(Get-Index $State $X $Y)]){$ALIVE_CELL_REPR}Else{$DEAD_CELL_REPR}) " -NoNewline`
4. To make it behave more like the Life implementations I've seen, you can clear the screen (`cls`) or move the cursor to the top of the console (`[Console]::CursorTop = 0`) between writes. The cursor method is faster.

Comment: Thank you. Honestly for 2., at the time, I couldn't figure out how to create a 2D array. Every attempt seemed to automatically flatten itself to 1D when I checked it, so I figured I'd just roll with it. And thanks for 4. I'll check that out.